# How can I swap between two images on infinite clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

How can I swap between two images on infinite clicks (not once) using JS or jQuery

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("img").attr("src","The New SRC");
});
```

This code works, but just once.

Comment: Check which src the image has to know which src it should become? Basic if/else ?

Comment: What do you mean by "forever"? Do you mean each time the page is reloaded. After the browser is closed and the visitor returns?

Comment: I mean that I can swap between images many times not just once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let make this simple as possible swap the src and data-src on click.

```js
$('.changeSrc').on('click', function(e){
  let src2= $('#img').data('src2');
  $('#img').data('src2', $('#img').attr('src'));
  alert(src2);
  $('#img').attr('src', src2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="img" src="./images/img1.jpg" data-src2="./images/img2.jpg"/>
<button class="changeSrc">Change Picture</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```js
var q = 0;

function swapImage() {
  if (q == 0) {
    document.getElementById("image").setAttribute('src', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562102010-558d6be6268e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80');
    q++;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("image").setAttribute('src', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567095740613-beef70b7e61c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80');
    q--;
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567095740613-beef70b7e61c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" onclick="swapImage();" />
```

Comment: what do you mean by that? It changes on every click. What do you need it to do exactly?

Comment: Unfortunately, it changes the images on just one click

Answer (score 0):

If by "forever" you mean your user will always see the same image once he's changed it, you need to store that information somewhere. Here's an example where you store the image source in the browser's local storage and read that to set the `src` property of the image element:

```html
<p>
  <img id="my-img" src="">
</p>

<button onclick="changeImage()">
  Change image
</button>

<script>
  const myImg = document.getElementById("my-img")
  const googleLogo = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
  const duckduckgoLogo = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png"
    
  const changeImage = () => {
    if(myImg.src === googleLogo) {
      myImg.src = duckduckgoLogo
      localStorage.setItem("img-src", duckduckgoLogo)
    } else {
     myImg.src = googleLogo
      localStorage.setItem("img-src", googleLogo)
    }
  }
  
  const getImageSrc = () => {
    const loadedSrc = localStorage.getItem("img-src")
    
    if(loadedSrc == null) {
     myImg.src = googleLogo
    } else {
     myImg.src = loadedSrc
    }
  }
  
  getImageSrc()
</script>
```

**Note:** The code is correct but it doesn't work in the snippet because I'm reading from `localStorage` and this seems to be not allowed inside a snippet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I mean that how can i change the images on infinite clicks